# jQuery .val() function returns 0

Tags: jquery

I'm probably overlooking something, but the jQuery .val function doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to target the string that's inside a list item, but it logs `0` instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list-item").click(function() {
        var list-item = $(this).val();
        console.log(list-item);
    });
});
```

Comment: Most list items don't have a value. Do you want the text content?

Comment: `list-item` is an invalid variable name. Also provide a [mcve]

Comment: Also, that code definitely didn't log anything. `list-item` is not a valid variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `.list-item` is an `li` element, the issue is because it doesn't have a `value` attribute to be retrieved. If you want to get the string inside the element, use `text()` instead.

Also note that having a variable named `list-item` is invalid; the `-` is the subtraction operator, so `list` and `item` would be expected to be variables by themselves. Note that I changed it to `listItem` in the example below:

```
$(".list-item").click(function() {
  var listItem = $(this).text();
  console.log(listItem);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

You should use `$(this).text();` instead of `$(this).val();`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".list-item").click(function() {
        var list-item = $(this).text();
        console.log(list-item);
    });
});
```

Comment: list-item? There's multiple issues here.

Answer (score 0):

in this case i think you should try instead of val, .text() instead of .val(),

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".list-item").click(function() {
    var listItem = $('.list-item').text();
    console.log(listItem);
  });
});
```

But, be sure that you want to get only one especific element of the list, in this case you need to change the type of selector your using.

Comment: Thank you for fixing the illegal identifier.